# Failed to resolve module specifier “express”. I am getting this error in my browser

Tags: node.js, express

**I have imported express in my code but it gives me this error.emphasized text**

---

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "express". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

---

Can somebody help me with this. Thanks.

*this my code in file app.js*

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
// import the routres
// The pages
// Used client

const homeRouter = require("./src/routes/home.route");

// The pages
// Used admin

const dachRouter = require("./admin/routes/dach.route");
const productsRouter = require("./admin/routes/products.route");
const categoriesRouter = require("./admin/routes/categories.route");

app.use(express.json())

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.set("views", [
  path.join(__dirname, "./src/views"),
  path.join(__dirname, "./admin/views"),
]);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./src/assets")));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"./admin/assets")));


app.use(express.static("./upload/admin"));

// client
app.all("/", homeRouter);

// admin
app.all("/admin", dachRouter);
app.all("/admin/products", productsRouter);
app.all("/admin/categories", categoriesRouter);
app.use((req,res)=>{
  res.send("and file send fhfhf fhf fh f f")
})
app.listen("3030", (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("run");
});
```

Comment: you should consider posting your code inline, not in a picture.

Comment: there is no error in your screens

Comment: I followed your instructions so take a look now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the title ("...I am getting this error in my browser"), you're running it clientside.

Express is meant to be used as a backend node project. It should be executed serverside

Comment: l have  import file by mistake

Comment: ```
import { ex } from "express";
```

~~~
import * as global from "./global.js";
const btnSubmitCategories = document.getElementById("btn");
const boxBtn = [...document.getElementsByClassName("evn")] 
~~~